# Can't apply hover to html grid item

Tags: css, grid

I use an html grid which contain cards as follows:

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(150px, auto) auto;
}

.card-area-1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.card-area-2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.card-area-1,
.card-area-2 {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 18px 0 rgba(0, 82, 145, 0.12);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.card-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.card-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.card-btn-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.card-btn-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="card-area-1"></div>
  <div class="card-area-2"></div>
  <div class="card-1">
    <div class="card-header">Header 1</div>
    <div class="card-content">Text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-2">
    <div class="card-header">Header 2</div>
    <div class="card-content">Text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-btn-1">
    <img src="proceed.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="card-btn-2">
    <img src="proceed.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I declared both card areas to apply css to,

My problem is that I'm unable to apply mouse hover state to card-area-1 and card-area-2,

Is there any way I can get something similar to:

```
.card-area-1:hover {
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is the `.card` on the `.card-area-1`. That's why the hover is not triggered. You can use `z-index` for `.card-area-1`

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(150px, auto) auto;
}

.card-area-1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.card-area-2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.card-area-1,
.card-area-2 {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 18px 0 rgba(0, 82, 145, 0.12);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.card-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.card-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.card-btn-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.card-btn-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.card-area-1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card-area-1:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="card-area-1"></div>
  <div class="card-area-2"></div>
  <div class="card-1">
    <div class="card-header">Header 1</div>
    <div class="card-content">Text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-2">
    <div class="card-header">Header 2</div>
    <div class="card-content">Text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-btn-1">
    <img src="proceed.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="card-btn-2">
    <img src="proceed.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```